# My dataFrame will not append this iloc dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to append rows of one dataframe into another dataframe. It's not going smoothly. I'm just trying to move it into a new DF for better visual representation. Could use the help, thanks!

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['compress', 'company', 'levenshtein score'])

for f in indexNumbers:
    print(new_df.iloc[f])
    dataframe.append((new_df.iloc[f]))
print(dataframe)
```

out:

```
compress               Arktkgz
company              Arktikgaz
levenshtein score          2.0
Name: 98, dtype: object
compress                Srgtnftegas
company              Surgutneftegas
levenshtein score               3.0
Name: 112, dtype: object
compress                          Sct Ntnl d'invstssmnt
company              Société Nationale d'Investissement
levenshtein score                                  14.0
Name: 126, dtype: object
compress                 MrsMrc
company              MarsaMaroc
levenshtein score           4.0
Name: 140, dtype: object
compress                    Albb Grp Hldng Ltd.
company              Alibaba Group Holding Ltd.
levenshtein score                           7.0
Name: 154, dtype: object
compress             Téhéran
company              Teheran
levenshtein score        2.0
Name: 168, dtype: object
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [compress, company, levenshtein score]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code without looping by using `loc` and passing the index numbers with:

```
dataframe = dataframe.append(new_df.loc[indexNumbers])
dataframe
```

This assumes `indexNumbers` is a list like `[1,3,6]`:

Comment: I did not know that! although I still am getting an empty dataframe

Comment: @anony123454323 did you set the result back to the initial dataframe? See my updated answer. It is not possible to return an empty dataframe when appending results to an existing dataframe.

Comment: Ack! That works.... but why do I have to set dataframe = ?

Comment: @anony123454323 `append` in the `pandas` library works different than normal `append` in python. You always have to set any changes to the dataframe back to the dataframe. If I have answered your question, then please kindly accept as solution by clicking the checkmark.